# Multiple-step OLE DB operation during publishing

Tags: publishing, 2011-sp1

I am getting this error when publishing to specific targets. I could not find any info in logs.

We are using Oracle DB and SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 version. This error is temporary and recurring.

Error: Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.

Any help on this would help me a lot.

Comment: "I could not find any info in logs." Which logs have you looked at? Did you set the loglevel of the deployer to DEBUG? Does the publish transaction even reach the deployer?

Comment: I checked event system logs. Now I am planning to enable Publisher log and set logback.xml to debug mode to see if I can find any more information. Thanks

Comment: Event system is generally unhelpful with Tridion content delivery errors as Tridion content delivery is a java application which uses SLF4J to configure its logging.

Answer (score 2):

What you have is a database error that is not specific to Tridion, but the layers underneath. So do a search for:

> Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB
>   status value, if available.

Here are a couple of links suggesting that the error is typically due to a bad connection string:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129744/multiple-step-ole-db-operation-generated-errors-check-each-ole-db-status-value
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20611837/multiple-step-ole-db-operation-generated-errors-check-each-ole-db-status-value